pdflatex says package says "File enumitem.sty not found." despite the file being present in TeX Live Utility
I was working on a document with the enumitem package, and I recieved the following error when building my document.tex file via the command pdflatex document.tex
! LaTeX Error: File `enumitem.sty' not found.

This is a really confusing error to me since I have used this package in my TeX documents for years. In fact, after compiling old tex files, I found that they are all broken and cannot build.
Looking at this stackexchange post from 4 years ago (Package not found by TeXstudio after update on Mac), I suspect that there is something which I recently installed on my computer that is somehow breaking the way my TexLive works, but I cannot figure out what it was.
I deleted MacTeX (following https://www.tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html) where I went to /usr/local/texlive and deleted the relevant files, but the error has persisted even after installing a fresh copy.
I have also checked Tex Live Utility, where it says the enumitem package is installed. Similarly, running sudo tlmgr install enumitem just tells me tlmgr install: package already present: enumitem.
For context, I am currently running pdflatex on an M3 MacBook Pro with Sonoma 14.4, with the following pdflatex version:
(base) ➜  ~ pdflatex -version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024/MacPorts 2024.70613_0)
kpathsea version 6.4.0
Copyright 2024 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.43; using libpng 1.6.44
Compiled with zlib 1.3.1; using zlib 1.3.1
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04


I honestly don't know much about how TeX Live works, so if there's something that I'm missing I would really appreciate any help. (I actually don't know if TeX Live is the problem or it's something else; I still have no idea how any of this file compilation stuff actually works).

welcome! that is not the pdflatex installed by MacTeX. that is the macports version. it uses a different location and different tree. enumitem is not installed in that tree. either uninstall the macports version of TL or ensure the MacTeX version is found first by making sure that is first in PATH.

what do (1) which pdflatex, (2) echo $PATH, (3) tlmgr version return?

Thank you so much for the help. I only installed macports for a project that I am now done with, so I just deleted it and now everything works again!

(after deleting macports) which pdflatex returns /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
echo $PATH returns
/Users/user/radioconda/bin:/Users/user/radioconda/condabin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin

and tlmgr version
returns
tlmgr revision 71331 (2024-05-24 09:30:36 +0200) tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2024 TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2024

be careful homebrew doesn't install texlive, too. that's earlier in your PATH, so if you install something with homebrew which depends on texlive, you'd have the same issue as with macports. just keep an eye on what it pulls in as dependencies. or change your PATH so MacTeX is first.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
